# Virtual Keyboard and Mouse

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I got Samples from MSDN for show virtual keyboard and all works at fine.

But if i'm connecting a Mouse to the device (Microsoft Surface ARM/x86) by USB, then in all samples is not showing virtual keyboard after touch by mouse.

If mouse is available, then virtual keyboard must not showing? If this is true, how i can input any words, if device have only 1 USB port, where already connected a mouse and i can't connect a Keyboard?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean? The keyboard shows up when you touch a text field even with mouse attached.

Comment: @FilipSkakun I want to understand, is have to showing keyboard after touch by mouse on textfield?

Comment: The virtual keyboard will display when you use touch. It will not display if you use a mouse.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Thanks, but i don't find any official information about this.

Comment: I'm not sure where you'd find something "official" for that. I can say with experience as I'm using a Microsoft Surface, that it works the way I describe.

Answer (score 0):

Use USB hub and a USB keyboard or use a Surface keyboard.

Comment: So, if i don't have a USB hub, then Virtual Keyboard will not safe a situation? This is a Rule of Microsoft? I don't find any information about this in MSDN. PLease help to find =)

Comment: No, I'm simply stating that if you want to use both mouse and keyboard - these are your options. If you want to use the on-screen~/virtual~ keyboard/SIP - you can touch a text field and it will show up. It's just the heuristic used to determine whether you want to use touch or mouse&keyboard. These are simply the most common input methods. I also sometimes want to do something different - actually the opposite to what you do - I use the physical keyboard on my laptop and want to use touch to select a field and it's a bit annoying when the OSK shows up, but that's the current logic.